# What country am I?

Tags: riddle, cipher, enigmatic-puzzle

4 ways to solve this, and solve all four to get an accept

Riddle:

> A city of two-fifths the U.S., but vaguely known
>
> A city of wisdom, But defeated by brutes
>
> A city of a painting, a school of thinkers.

Enigmatic stuff:

> Virto estas forta kiam kunigitaj
>
> Umodzi, ntchito, wakutemwa
>
> Li dejjem Konxja ta 'Alla Aħna jaspiraw, Ibni u bil-Quddiem bħala poplu wieħed
>
> Uharteak bezala-bezala-Sultan
>
> Galutinis vainikuoja darbą

Once you have solved the 1st 2, come and solve this one! (hint: 1st 2 answers needed.)

Cipher:

> EDDADLEGDFBZECDLDFEDEFGBZDCDI

Yet Another Riddle:

> To solve me
>
> You must first disintegrate me
>
> First I am one off of female
>
> The link of she and her
>
> Next I am a device
>
> One which is used in fall
>
> Or can be used do describe claws
>
> Finally I am the king
>
> One of golden birth
>
> The fiercest of them all
>
> Now string them together
>
> to get what city?

Comment: The title says "what country" and the last line of the final riddle says "what city". Are both of those as intended, bleh?

Comment: "A city of two-fifths the U.S., but vaguely known". The city is in the US or its size/population is two-fifths of the US??

Comment: I assume it means something like "2/5 of US states have a town or city of that name".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan the last riddle goes to a city, and the whole thing relates to a country

Comment: OK. So "4 ways to solve this" doesn't really mean what it says? It's actually "4 things all of which need solving to solve this"?

Comment: No, actually, you can pretty much guess what it is after you solve one.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the country we're looking for is

> Greece.

**First riddle**

I don't think I have all the references but I think this refers to

> Athens. There are 22 Athenses in the US, though most are rather small; it produced a lot of philosophers in ancient times, and was defeated by Sparta in the Peloponnesian War; I think the painting/school line refers to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_School_of_Athens).

**Enigmatic stuff**

Google Translate renders these into English thus:

> Virtue is stronger when united (Esperanto)
>  One, work, love of (Chichewa)
>  Always aware of God We aspire, Build and Advance as one people (Maltese)
>  Islands like-as-Sultan (Basque)
>  The final icing on the cake (Lithuanian)

and various people in the comments have improved the translations and/or identified them as national mottoes:

> Andorra: Virtus unita fortior (virtue united is stronger); translated into Esperanto
>  Rwanda: Ubumwe, Umurimo, Gukunda Igihugu (unity, work, patriotism); translated into Chichewa
>  Grenada: Ever conscious of God we aspire, build and advance as one people; translated into Maltese
>  *unknown*: [something to do with islands and sultans]; translated into Basque
>  Seychelles: Finis coronat opus (the end crowns the work); translated into Lithuanian.

Perhaps

> the fourth one is the motto of somewhere beginning with O (Oman would be the obvious candidate but it doesn't seem to have any such motto; nor, so far as I can tell, did the Ottoman Empire; at that point I'm running out of "O"s), yielding Argos, a city in Greece.

**Cipher**

The distribution of the letters suggests putting A=1 etc. and interpreting pairs as hexadecimal representations of ASCII characters. The obstacles to this are (1) that there are 29 letters in the ciphertext and (2) that they include two Ls and two Zs. The Ls are OK -- just treat JKLMNO as hex digits ABCDEF -- but what about the Z? Well, in the comments M Oehm makes the excellent suggestion that Z means zero -- it always comes right after a B, making BZ=20=space.

Having an odd number of characters feels like a fatal obstacle, but in fact the questioner has confirmed that the ASCII interpretation is correct. Perhaps at some point it will become clear why a letter is missing. (Note added later -- see spoilered text below for more details --: actually it looks as if we have an *extra* letter, not a *missing* letter.)

Anyway, we have EDDADLEGDFBZECDLDFEDEFGBZDCDI which yields 54414C574620534C4654567204349, which yields these obvious pairs: 54 41 4C 57 46 20 53 4C 46 54 56 7 20 43 49 so if we're just missing a single letter it had better be a D or E before that second G. ASCII-decoding yields TALWF_SLFTV?_CI where underscores are spaces and ? is either G or W.

So now all we need to do is to crack the cipher. We don't have much to work on so it had better be a simple one. It isn't a Caesar (no shift yields anything that makes sense). We're told that the first two answers are needed; perhaps we should use them as a Vigenere key or something. Well,

> using ATHENSARGOS as key yields either THESSALONHECP or THESSALONHOCP, depending on whether the missing letter is D (-> G) or E (-> W). Clearly this is going to be THESSALONIKI or perhaps THESSALONIKE, and clearly either (1) we need two extra letters of key from somewhere or (2) something other than a missing letter has happened to the ciphertext.

Now,

> suppose we just delete the mysterious G instead of trying to turn it into an extra letter, and de-Vigenere. Aha, then we get THESSALONHKI which is very nearly right. The H-that-should-be-I is in the position corresponding to the unconfirmed O of ARGOS. For de-Vigenere-ing to yield an I instead we'd need ARGNS, but that doesn't seem like it makes any sense (it's not a Greek city any more). But if the surplus letter is not the second G but the F that precedes it, then we get THESSALONIKI. I think I can believe that.

The big remaining question is

> why there's an extra F in the ciphertext. I have no good explanation for that yet.

**Second riddle**

I'm pretty sure this is

> another Greek city, Heraklion, split up as He/rak/lion. "He" is "she" without its first letter and the common part of "she" and "her"; "rak" should presumably be understood as "rake" (an implement used in the fall or autumn; something claws can do); and the lion is commonly called the king of animals and is indeed fierce.

**What's missing**

So we've got almost everything at this point. What remains unexplained? In order of appearance:

> It's not perfectly clear why "but vaguely known" (perhaps just because most of the Athenses aren't big famous cities). We haven't identified the fourth motto, though Oman is a semi-plausible candidate. We don't know why there's an extra F in the ciphertext. And in the final riddle I'm not altogether satisfied by "he" as "one off of female" nor by "rake" in place of "rak", and I'm not exactly sure why a lion is "of golden birth".

Of these,

> the only things that are definitely holes in the answer (rather than places where the question is a little vague or my understanding a little fuzzy) are the O of Argos, and the extra F.

Comment: Lithuanian sounds wrong

Comment: Actually all of them are a little bit off, but you'll manage :)

Comment: The Lithuanian phrase is actually a translation of Ovid's saying _Finis Coronat Opus_ ("The end crowns the work"), which is the motto in the coat of arms of the Seychelles. That makes me wonder whether the other sayings also have a representation in Latin which are state or city mottoes.

Comment: @MOehm The Maltese one is Grenada's (in English).

Comment: There are a whole lot of mottos that mention "unity" and "work", but I think Rwanda has the best match for the third word: "patriotism".

Comment: The first one is Andorra.

Comment: @f'': Very good. You're right about Rwanda. Google Translate gives the variant in the question after a bit of fiddling. Now we have pairs of countries and languages. I guess there's something that can be done to the country and language codes (ad-eo; rw-ny; gd-mt; ??-eu; sc-lt).

Comment: The initial letters of the countries then go ARG_S but so far as I can tell no country with first letter U has a motto resembling the fourth one.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Maybe it's O?

Comment: That would pretty much have to be Oman, which would fit well with the reference to a Sultan, but the country doesn't appear to have a motto.

Comment: The Maldives are islands and used to have a sultan but I don't see any sign that they ever had a motto like that.

Comment: Your decoding idea isn't bad. Z could be zero: It occurs twice and each time after B, which would yield the space character (#20). If we assume that the rest must be uppercase letters, which start with D or E, there must be an omission between F and G, where either a D ("G") or an E ("W") goes. That yields "TALWF SLFTV(G|W) CI", which still has to be made sense of.

Comment: The decoding is actually correct. Oxford is not though

Comment: Ah, Z=zero is a clever idea I should have thought of. If there's an omission -- which there clearly needs to be unless e.g. some other single character means "line break" or something -- then I hope it will be corrected (if an error) or clarified by the rest of the puzzle (if not)...

Comment: I currently think the languages are arbitrary.

Comment: Erm, Raphael's most famous work?

Comment: @Strawberry: I was just editing that into my answer as you wrote it :-).

Comment: Thats all of them man. The F is probably a mistake on my part. Oman didnt have a motto so I used the national song

Comment: Ah! I did notice that Oman's national anthem was very sultanish, but the translation mystifies me. Does "Uharteak" mean something other than "islands", then? (I know no Basque at all.)

Answer (score 3):

**Community Evidence Locker**

A city two-fifths of the US:

> OP changed from "half" to "2/5".  A later comment clarifies it to emphasize *about* 2/5. We know it is ***NOT*** Clinton, Franklin, Washington, Madison, Marion, Jackson, Jefferson, Springfield, Greenville, Salem, Troy, Lexington, Monroe, Chester, Arlington, Lebanon, Ashland, Canton, Oxford, or Mount Vernon.

A city of wisdom, but defeated by brutes:

> Alexandria? Athens?

A city of a painting, a school of thinkers:

> Maybe Paris... (The MonaLisa painting)

Comment: I'm pretty sure i counted correctly on the 1/2 of the states but its noton there

Comment: @bleh uh oh. Hmmm, I better check my sources.

Comment: Ok I miscounted

Comment: It's around 2/5 so dont go exactly 20. *of around two-fifths* doesnt sound right.

Comment: Go with more cities- still not on there. But it is on the answer....